# AJAX - What exactly does that encompass?

Tags: javascript, ajax

So I see on a lot of people's resumes they list AJAX in their technologies (or programming languages - and I recognize that it is not a language). To me, AJAX seems like such a small concept to be individually listed. It seems it is almost as useful as listing MVC experience (because MVC too is a concept), which is good to know, but AJAX, like MVC, is just a facet of one's abilities as a developer. However, saying "I know AJAX" seems like it is much smaller thing than saying "I know MVC".

What does saying "I know AJAX" actually cover?

To me, it seems like you are saying, I know how to use JavaScript to send of an asynchronous call (via some data format like XML or JSON) to a web endpoint, and use the endpoint's response to manipulate a web page's DOM for visual effects and data.

The [wikipedia page on AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) lists just  a few more things, but I'd love to ask the community... am I missing a key concept about AJAX? If not, it seems like that listing it on a resume is just fluff.

Comment: "I know AJAX" means you can defend that statement to the hiring manager when you make it past HR's filtering out all resumes that don't have 'AJAX' in them.

Comment: Have you ever had AJAX bugs to resolve that involved multiple threads and variable issues because the success or error function is running in a different scope?

Comment: @JBKing No, because JavaScript is no multithreaded. It is, however, event-driven, which causes the point of execution to jump around when events occur.  :-)  I hear there's a new Worker thing defined in HTML 5 that will probably drive JavaScript to become multithreaded sooner than later, though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639224/javascript-multithreading would note some multi-threading in brosers for a source on my side. Do you have a source that says JS only runs in 1 thread and can't split execution to more than that thread?

Comment: @JBKing JavaScript isn't multithreaded. Google Gears is both depracated and external to JavaScript. MS Silverlight is C# running in the .NET CLR, is definitely multithreaded, and just as definitely is not JavaScript. Native JavaScript mechanisms like setInterval, yield, et al let you halt and jump into event handlers then return to the previous point of execution when the handler function returns, but that is *not* multithreading. HTML5 Workers looks like the ticket, and even that is apparently external to JavaScript itself, but will presumably be available in any HTML5-compliant environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are thinking like a programmer. Instead, try to think like a Human Resources Director.

> Senior Developer to Human Resources Director: We need to hire a web developer.
>
> HRD: Okay, what skills do they need to have?
>
> SRD: Well, PHP, Javascript, MVC frameworks, git...
>
> HRD: Anything else?
>
> SRD: Well, experience with AJAX would be a plus...

Adding technologies like AJAX into resumes works as grease to facilitate Human Resources filtering out potential job applications and to write accurate job listings.

Otherwise, you are correct. If I were hiring a web developer, I would assume that PHP + Javascript on a resume would imply having written code with asynchronous calls. But I would still ask during an interview if it wasn't explicitly stated.